Version mismatch error for dataproc serveless runtime 1.2
I want to run a spark job based on scala 2.12.15 and spark 3.3.4 with sparkBigQueryConnectorVersion = "0.28.1".
I just upgraded the runtime of dataproc serverless from 1.1 to 1.2 since i need to upgrade from java 11 to java 17 by also changing the library versions in build.sbt to following:
val sparkVersion = "3.5.1"
val sparkBigQueryConnectorVersion = "0.36.4"
val sparkAvroVersion = "3.5.1"

val sparkCore = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided"
val sparkSql = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided"
val sparkHive = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion % "provided"
val sparkBigQueryConnector = "com.google.cloud.spark" %% "spark-bigquery-with-dependencies" % sparkBigQueryConnectorVersion
val sparkAvro = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-avro" % sparkAvroVersion`

to support the versions specified here in the dataproc serverless 1.2 documentation https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/concepts/versions/spark-runtime-1.2
However, I receive an error:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider not a subtype
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:593)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1244)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273) 
...

I run a airflow dag with the following config:
batch_config = {
"spark_batch": {  # Use 'spark_batch' for Spark jobs in Dataproc Serverless
  "jar_file_uris": [
    f"{artifact_bucket}/bq-ingestion-{release_id}.jar"
  ],
  "main_class": "de.mobile.dmh.campaign.ingestion.ExecutableCampaignsIngestion",
  "args": ["--startDate", start_date, "--endDate", end_date, "--outputDs", target_ds]
},
"environment_config": {  # Corrected to use environment_config for serverless
  "execution_config": {
    "subnetwork_uri": subnetwork_uri,  # Specify subnetwork
    "service_account": service_account  # Specify service account
  }
},
"runtime_config": {  # Specify the runtime version for Dataproc Serverless
  "version": "1.2",
  "properties": {  # Spark properties moved here under 'properties'
    "spark.executor.memory": "4g",
    "spark.executor.cores": "4",
  }
}}


The issue you're encountering is due to a version mismatch between your Spark version, the BigQuery connector version, and the runtime environment of Dataproc Serverless

Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider not a subtype
indicates a compatibility problem, usually caused by using a mismatched version of the BigQuery connector with Spark.

Thats what i dont understand, why versions are not compatible? even tho i used the one in the dataproc documentation @AliSaberi
